# Intellij (Android Studio) shortcut to select build variant

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

In `IntelliJ` (`Android Studio`) is there a quick way to change the current build variant (flavour) without having to use the mouse? Or is there and easy way to customise `IntelliJ` to provide this functionality?

Comment: You can set your custom shortcut(but mouse selection is required) as Yuril Mistyac's answer I tried the same and it's working.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this under the `Settings` menu.

`Settings`->`Keymap` and add `Select Build Variant` Shortcut.

Use the `Select Build Variant` shortcut to focus on the build variant table, select needed module's variant row, and press `F2` to invoke popup.

Comment: problem is that you can open 'select build variant' panel and IDE focus will move there but then you can't use keyboard to actually change selected build variant - you still need to use your mouse and click there anyway. Or maybe I miss something

Comment: Yes, we need to use a mouse for the changed variant, did you find any solution?

Comment: @Arbaz.in yes, I've updated the answer, jpanel column in android plugin support only F2 key (113 key code)

Comment: @YuriMisyac Not getting it, tried same but the popup is not coming, can you please explain in more details.
i have  set a shortcut called **ctrl+shift+,** its just open the build variant menu not for seletion.